# Styling submit button 'error'?

Tags: html, css, submit

I am trying to style a submit button, but for some reason this is not working. I tried setting the height and it's not working. I got an example from W3 schools, styled it just the same and that's not working. Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem? Hopefully the following code is enough, but if it's not I can edit this post.

https://snag.gy/bpdTU8.jpg

Code:

```
 <!-- Div that holds the form element -->
 .mainBox {
 padding-top: 15px;
 margin: auto;
 background-color:#998200;
 width: 65%;
 color: black;

 }
input[type=submit] {
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: try adding `display: block` inside of the css for the input.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much.

Comment: Well I guess there is just one big  problem. It alters all the previous positioning/aligning  for my form elements. Not to sure how to restore that.

Comment: could you please show any other code that it might be affecting so that I may update my answer? thanks :) also, if this helped you, please consider selecting my answer as correct. :)

Comment: @Shinji-san please let me know what you wan't exactly.

Comment: Sure thing. I add a <br> after each input element, in case you need that info. Here's the rest of the CSS code, please let me know if you need the HTML. I just don't want to have to do all the editing if I don't need it.

https://jsfiddle.net/f0sLzx8m/

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic Ok sure I will edit this post along with the full JS fiddle of what I'm after.

Comment: @Shinji-san look at the edit for my answer! no need for a jsfiddle now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the input CSS, try adding `display: block;`. Like so:

```
input[type=submit] {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**EDIT:**

change `display: block` to `display: inline-block`

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: For some reason display: block alters the whole layout though. I used to have all my input headers to the left of the box, but now every other input header is to above and to the right of the text fields. Would you know how to fix that issue?

Comment: @Shinji-san no problem! have fun with building your website :) p.s: chuck us an upvote ;))

Comment: Oh I will, and you'll have fun too if you play YGO. How? O.O. Oh, I checked off your answer.